# I am trying to form a rectangle with 2 pairs of Coordinate in TCL

Tags: tcl, synopsys-vcs

I am new to TCL and hardware design. I am currently doing a script that could verify all the ports at an edge and make a rectangle box that cover all the ports at an edge.

Since I am new to TCL, I think there is something wrong in the syntax.
[image]

The error msg is:

Error: Invalid coordinates '$bbox_coor_x1 [expr $bbox_coor_y2-30]' in list. (NDMUI-100)
Error: Empty or invalid geometry specified for the '-boundary' argument of the command. (NDMUI-337).

Please help me.

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is that variables and commands are not interpolated inside curly braces.  Please learn the difference between curlies and double quotes.

For example:

```
set x 5
set y 10

# Curlies
puts {$x $y}
   --> $x $y  (literally)
puts {$x [expr $y+1]}
   --> $x [expr $y+1]  (literally)

# Double quotes
puts "$x $y"
   --> 5 10

# List command
puts [list $x $y]
   --> 5 10
puts [list $x [expr $y+1]]
   --> 5 11
```

When making a list of lists, like a bbox, anything inside outer-most curlies will interpolate:

```
puts "{$x $x} {$y $y}"
   --> {5 5} {10 10}
```

One more thing, note that `lindex` can take multiple indexes.  Do this instead of calling lindex twice.

```
lindex $bbox 0 1
```